# Running android espresso tests, but nothing happens

Tags: android, functional-testing, android-espresso

I managed to get espresso tests up and running last week. Wrote tests for a few days and when I went to go run the tests yesterday, the report files weren't being created. All I see is an index file displaying 0 tests. I'm running connectedInstrumentTest in the CL and it builds successfully.

Any ideas on what the issue could be?

Comment: It could be anything. If you have a source control system, I recommend you get the old code from there and compare. Also, try to create a brand new project and implement some tests, it may help.

Comment: So I figured out that I need to have the app running on the device -__- Felt kinda dumb but it happens to all of us I suppose!